# splitting name into first, middle, last

Tags: regex, perl, split

Wanting to split into first, middle and last names from a name formatted like the following:

```
# this is the format
$full_name = 'lastname, firstname (middleinitial)'
# this is what it would look like
$full_name = 'Doe, John (D)'
```

The names always follow this format. These would be stored in the variables `first`, `middle` and `last`. `middle` should not contain any parenthesis. Yes, the split function would be fine to use here; however, `full_name` isn't guaranteed to contain a string. It could be:

```
$full_name = ''
```

I'm not sure if split could work with something like that. What would be the best way to split up the names like I've described?

Comment: Could you please provide a few test samples with edge cases included?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Note that there are people without middle initials (me, for example). You need to ensure that your system handles names like mine, too. Actually, in some countries, there are people who use just one name - no 'lastname', just a 'name'.  And then there are those with multiple words in the surname (van der Linden, for example). If you're dealing with toy data for a class, you can get away with ignoring such details. If you're writing code for the 'real world', you need to accommodate such issues.

Comment: Edited with more info. Not sure what you mean by 'edge cases' Lidrian. IceArdor - right, there are a lot of name-splitting perl examples here on SO. I guess the keyword here is 'best'. I hate always having to put a 'I've already looked around SO...' disclaimer on every SO post, but here it is. Jonathan - good call. The ()'s would be empty in that case.

Comment: Edge cases would be names like Martin Luther King, Jr. which contains a comma.

Comment: Also don't forget those that have apostrophe's and hyphens in their names. Some websites insist I've entered my name in incorrectly because it has "invalid characters," yet when I remove these characters, my name doesn't match the name they have on file. I try escaping these characters in the HTML text fields, but this doesn't get through their systems either.

Comment: @IceArdor: I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $full_name = 'Doe, John (D)';
my ($last, $first, $middle) = $full_name =~ /([\w'-]+)/g;

print "First: $first\nMiddle: $middle\nLast: $last";
```

Output:

```
First: John
Middle: D
Last: Doe
```

Comment: I assume names may have apostrophes, hyphens and spaces.

Comment: @Borodin - But the OP doesn't: "The names always follow this format."  Nevertheless, your point's well made.  Used a character class to which apostrophes and hyphens can be added.  Spaces are, however, problematic.  Appreciate your comment.

Comment: Might want to add that `$first`, `$middle`, and `$last` will be `undef` if `$full_name` is the empty string (which the OP said is possible).

Comment: My guess is that *"this format"* means `/.+, .+ \(.+\)/`. If we were to take your interpretation then *all* the names will be `John D Doe` and there is nothing to do. Unless this is an exercise, you aren't allowing for `M'Kobe-Dan Simon Ratonhnhaké:ton D'Souza Lyon-Smith-Sykes`

Comment: @Borodin - *Guess* is the operative here, no?  "Format" is  equivocal, given the OP's specs.  The solution also doesn't accommodate the following [proper names](http://www.neatorama.com/2008/05/19/10-strangest-names-evar#!pGj7D): "Urhines Kendall Icy Eight Special K", "Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116" and "@" (yes, just "@").  Given this, what regex  does one conger for capturing (parts of) names that can be called 'good?'  Of course, it should minimize exceptions, but that engineering tolerance is a function of dataset variation, of which the OP's dataset may have  little.

Comment: @Kenosis: Well what is your guess? Making up clearly impossible names doesn't help your case. I presume the example you give would be `Kendall, Urhiness` or perhaps `Kendall, Urhiness (IESK)`. I think it's highly unlikely that the names the OP has to deal with have no spaces, yet your idea makes a mess of `Middleton Gretch, Adam (D C)` which is unambiguous given the OP's data format.

Comment: @kenosis: Thank you, but I'm not sure what your comment means. It's certainly *"not constructive"* and potentially *"rude or offensive"*. Since you don't raise a specific problem with my comments, I can understand only that you agree but wish I was wrong. Your solution is faulty in all but the most simple context, and the OP should be aware of that.

Comment: @Borodin - My intent is not to be either rude or offensive, but it is constructive.  You're implicitly suggesting that the OP doesn't know any better, but somehow you *do* 'know' the OP's dataset; thus, you need to school the OP about name variance and proper regex selection.  Certainly, my solution is not robust.  However, this is not a dissertation topic.  Don't get me wrong; I always learn a lot from you.  But now the term "perseveration" comes to mind.  "...I can understand only that you agree but wish I was wrong."  This is a rather sad and tragic statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $full_name = 'Doe, John (D)';
my ($last, $first, $middle) = split /[,() ]+/, $full_name;
```

Comment: To understand your answer better - so it splits whenever it sees `','`, `'('`, `')'` or `' '`? Also - will this work if I have an empty string?

Comment: @EvanDefend yes it splits on these chars and matches them as many it can. When empty string, variables are undef.

Comment: @mpacep The output for that is `'Doe`, `John`, `D`, `'`. Also, it is generally expected that you _explain_ your code when answering a question.

Comment: @RyanCarlson I'm not sure if I follow you correctly?

Comment: @mpapec Whoops. I completely missed the fact that the `'`s were the ends of the string. It should actually split into `Doe`, `John`, `D)`. According to http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html, "when assigning to a list, if LIMIT is omitted (or zero), then LIMIT is treated as though it were one larger than the number of variables in the list;"

Comment: @RyanCarlson https://eval.in/78496

Comment: @mpapec ... Just ignore me and my stupidity.

Comment: @RyanCarlson delimiters are `,() ` chars in any order and as much as possible (`+` makes greedy).

Comment: @mpapec As I said earlier, ignore me and my stupidity.

Comment: `D'Souza Lyon-Smith-Sykes, M'Kobe-Dan (S R)`

Answer (score 0):

You can match those with a shorthand character class: `\w+`

Surely that's not what you're asking for?

If you wanted to make it more complex:

`(^\w+)|((?<=\s)\w+(?=\s))|(\w+(?=\)))`

Which would capture:

- Firstname `group 1`
- Lastname `group 2`
- Initial `group 3`

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't as simple as it looks, and the answer depends on the *actual* data.

Given the vague specification and no more I would write this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name_possibles = qr/[^ \s , ( ) [:cntrl:] ]/x;
my $name_re        = qr/(?: $name_possibles+ (?: \s+ $name_possibles+ )* )/x;

my $full_name = 'Doe, John (D)';

my @parts = $full_name =~ /($name_re), \s* ($name_re) \s* \( \s* ($name_re) \s* \)/xg;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@parts;
```

**output**

```
["Doe", "John", "D"]
```

Comment: @mpapec: Does it look better now? It's hard to write tidy regexes